# Create an new DenseMatrix from an submatrix in Breeze using Scala

Tags: scala, matrix, linear-algebra, scala-breeze

I've a `DenseMatrix (original)`. I slice it to remove the last column (`subset`). After that I want to access the data in the subset. However, `subset.data` still points to the data in the old `DenseMatrix` (`original`). Any idea what I'm missing here and how to fix this ?

```
original: breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Int] = 
1    200  3  0    
10   201  4  0    
111  200  0  100  
150  195  0  160  
200  190  0  150  

scala> val numcols = original.cols
numcols: Int = 4

scala> val subset = original(::, 0 to numcols - 2)
subset: breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Int] = 
1    200  3  
10   201  4  
111  200  0  
150  195  0  
200  190  0  

scala> subset.data
res0: Array[Int] = Array(1, 10, 111, 150, 200, 200, 201, 200, 195, 190, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 160, 150)

scala> subset.data.size
res1: Int = 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I figured out one way of doing it.

by using the following

```
scala> subset.toDenseMatrix.data
res10: Array[Int] = Array(1, 10, 111, 150, 200, 200, 201, 200, 195, 190, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0)

scala> subset.toDenseMatrix.data.size
res11: Int = 15
```

Comment: FWIW, slices of DenseVectors and DenseMatrices are always views in Breeze. .toDenseMatrix or .copy is the way to get around that.